# Can the memory on heap be modified between two consecutive C statements in a single threaded process

Tags: c, linux

I ran a static code analysis tool on the chunk of source code that I have been asked maintain. The tool returned an error in the following situation:

```
n = foo1(k);
if (n == -1)
goto err:
i = foo2(k); // k is a pointer to an integer and is allocated on the heap; i is an integer)
memcpy(x,y, i);
```

The error states that i can potentially be assigned a value of -1 and therefore memcpy can cause errors (I can provide details on how but they are not relevant to this problems)

The function foo1 and foo2  both have  the following code in the beginning

```
if (!k)
return -1;
```

In the lines above, **if we reach the line where foo2 is called, are we guaranteed that k will not be null,** because, if it were NULL then n would have been equal to -1 and we would have never reached to the point of invocation of foo2.
This code is part of a a single threaded process running in user space on Linux so I believe that there is no one else apart from this process that can touch the memory space pointed to by k in between the execution of foo1 and foo2.

Comment: Avoiding `goto` is a *good programming practice*

Comment: So you are asking if the warning from your analysis tool was indeed a problem? If that is the question then I would answer yes, the tool is correct. But not because a regular program flow allows such situation to occur - just as you stated, it would not happen. Instead I think it just is not defensive enough. Why not checking for -1 again? Imagine a hectic day and someone starts patching stuff into this code that suddenly does allow k to be invalid on the start of foo2...

Comment: Short version of what @Till commented: static analyzers don't typically dive into this (even shallow) level of understanding that it's not possible to have an error. Humans are much better at the realities, while lint (et. al.) is much faster at finding the spots for the human to review.

Comment: Imagine what happens when you start saying things like, "this analysis tool spits errors but it's OK because...". The result is that you make that tool useless for detecting *real* errors in your code, because they are drowned out by "OK errors". Same goes for compiler warnings, for example.

Comment: Regarding `goto`, it could be avoided with simply `if (n != -1)` and some braces, and although poor style, has nothing to do with your question. If this is like most static analyzers I've used in the past, it formulates test scenarios. There is a reason why [`memcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) takes a `size_t` unsigned value. Your *compiler* should be warning you in the first place for using an `int` where a `size_t` belongs, assuming your warning level is set correctly (and if it isn't, the static analyzer output is the least of your worries)

Comment: Why is there a `:` and not a `;` at the end of the  `goto` statement?

Comment: @UmerFarooq Apart from the suspicious `:`, the `goto` in the question's code looks exactly how a proper use of `goto` for error-handling in a C program would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is: Yes, the call to `foo1()` could potentially modify the memory allocated at `k`.

The longer answer is that code analysis tools are pretty dumb. They only go so far to "understand" your code. A famous example is the GCC compiler which was millions of times faster to execute this loop than other C compilers at the time:

```
 int i;
 for(i=0; i<10000000; i++);
```

It simply noticed that the loop body was empty and replaced this with `int i = 10000000;` (omitting the loop) and then it noticed that `i` was never used and dropped everything.

But even pretty simple code can confuse a code analysis tool. That's why you need to learn how to configure it properly (which often means to mark a piece of code as "this works, go away.")